# How to edit instance of class?

Tags: python, class

I am making a puzzle game with Python, it's supposed to be a 3x3 slide puzzle. I've made a class that stores name/id and x,y coordinates.

In the function `up()` I want to move the asterisk (`*`) up one row and in theory it should work but apparently not. I have a function that finds the class instance associated with two coordinates (`find()`) and it returns an instance of the class called `symbol`.

**Layout of the slide puzzle:**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 *
```

When I try to assign the new values to the class instance above me (represented by the 6) nothing gets assigned. I would like to use the global keyword but that seems like such a hassle because then I would have to check every coordinate and then say what variable to change.

This is a puzzle game so it's really important that the player can move around without issues. I haven't tried anything else since I don't know how to proceed from this point.

```py
class symbol:

    def __init__(self, x, y, val):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.val = val

s1 = symbol(1, 1, "1")
s2 = symbol(2, 1, "2")
s3 = symbol(3, 1, "3")

s4 = symbol(1, 2, "4")
s5 = symbol(2, 2, "5")
s6 = symbol(3, 2, "6")

s7 = symbol(1, 3, "7")
s8 = symbol(2, 3, "8")
s9 = symbol(3, 3, "*")


def getPos():
    xPos = 0
    yPos = 0
    for element in symbols:
        if element.val == "*":
            xPos = element.x
            yPos = element.y
        else:
            pass

    return xPos, yPos

def find(x, y):
    xPos = 0
    yPos = 0
    found = symbol(100, 100, "FIND")

    for element in symbols:
        if element.x == x and element.y == y:
            found.x = x
            found.y = y
            found.val = element.val
        else:
            pass
    return found

def up():
    x, y = getPos()

    if y > 1:
        newBlock = find(x, y-1)
        myBlock = find(x, y)

        myBlock.val = newBlock.val
        newBlock.val = "*"
        clear()
        draw()
        print(f"myBlock: {myBlock.val} ({myBlock.x}, {myBlock.y}), newBlock: {newBlock.val} ({newBlock.x}, {newBlock.y})")
    else:
        pass
        #cannot go higher
```

Comment: I'd recommend watching a few videos about how classes and instance/class methods work in python. From what you've written, it appears that you are still quite new to python. Here's a [short article about it.](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/). From a quick youtube search, [this video](https://youtu.be/wfcWRAxRVBA) looks like it might have some useful content for you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add code to turn it into a [mcve] especially with an example of it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `find` function is making a new `symbol` and returning that. When `up()` modifies the result of `find()`, it's just changing some copy that lives outside of (what I assume is) your list of symbols.

One solution would be to just return the element from the list in `find`. i.e.

```
for element in symbols:
    if element.x == x and element.y == y:
        return element
return None
```

Comment: Aha! I didn't know it was possible to use return inside a for-loop.